# How to implement boost rules for SXA search results in Sitecore

Tags: sxa, solr, sxa-search, boosting

We are using Sitecore 9.0 (solr 5.0), soon migrating to 10.2 (solr 6.3).

I am referring Sitecore documents -

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/search-result-boosting.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/boost-search-results-for-sxa-site-queries.html

I tried in both Sitecore versions by adding some rules and adding boost value to 1.1. But there is no impact on search results.

Is there something which is missing or being done wrong. Do I need to configure something else in code level or content level?

Any kind of suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How your Solr query looks like after adding boosting rules? Do you see boosting syntax in the search.log?

Comment: Are you using a custom / GEO-based sorting? If so, try without sorting to check the boosting feature in isolation.